# Permission denied firebase.push()

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-security

I'm using firebase with java. I used to add data by

```
firebaseRef.child("users").push().setValue(user);
```

where my `user` is object from `User.class` with the following attributes

```
String name;
String id;
```

When I added validation to the data to accept input that has id equals to a secret key `id === 'secret id'` as following

```
"user": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".validate": "newData.hasChild('id')",
    "id": {
        ".validate": "newData.val() === 'secret id'"
    }
}
```

it shows me permission denied, I've tried many cases according to their documentation but I got the same permission denied.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, Firebase.push() generates new id so `newData` doesn't refer to it anymore, I made a variable to represent that id so that I can access my data normally

```
"user": {
    "$key": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        ".validate": "newData.hasChild('id')",
        "id": {
            ".validate": "newData.val() === 'secret id'"
        }
    }
}
```